# For Node Js Server how to refer static html files from different folder

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I have server js set up as

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public/DirName'));

var ipaddress = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP || '127.0.0.1';
```

now because of use of dir for express it picks up index.html from /public/DirName but in that index.html if we have to refer a html file from diff folder how to refer that ? using general URL will result into request to the node server and o/p will be 
"Cannot GET /public/diffrentFolder/file.HTML"

how to avoid this?

Answer (score 1):

You can mention another path like this

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public/other_DirName'));
```

Node will look the file in directory depends on the order provided by delcaration.

Like in this case, it look for the file first in `/public/DirName` and then `/public/other_DirName`.

Comment: its not working ..I have added the path, as well as I have diff html file name as you mentioned..

Comment: Please check in network tab.I might be your path declaration or use of it is wrong